# Display a List of Events with "Month Year" Headers with Low Events

Tags: events, low-events

We have a channel with events in it, and are utilizing Low Events. The design calls for a list of events, with Month Year as a heading, such as this:

**January 2014**

- Event 1 Details
- Event 2 Details

**February 2014**

- Event 3 Details
- Event 4 Details

... and so on.

I suspect I need to compare the month/year of entry i with that of entry i-1; if they're not the same, display the month/year of entry i. What's the best way of doing that?

It looks like EE has a native tag pair for handling this, {date_heading display="monthly"}, but that appears to be based on the entry_date, and not the value of my Low Events field. It appears that Low Events has the ability to sync the date of the events field with the entry_date, but would prefer to keep them unrelated if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the [:first modifier](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/fieldtype#first) to generate those headings.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If that's a Stash build, you could simply use [this method](https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973) for ordering entries by month and then by year (or any variation). Used it on a recent build. Works flawlessly.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, but going with the :first modifier as it's much quicker to implement in this situation.

Comment: Agree. Stash would be the solution for more complex cases.